# How to filter data by screen

Tags: swift, realm

I'm new to Realm (Swift) and try to adopt the best architecture.

Let's say I have a screen 1 where I load object A, B and C that I save in Realm database and display. Then I go to screen 2 where I load the same type object, but I load other objects C, D and E. If I come back to screen 1, I don't want to find myself with A, B, C, D and E. I want to find A, B, and C like before, so I need to filter.

I thought about 2 strategies :
The first one is to keep in screen 1 an Array of uuids of my object and avec a Results where I query object that my table of uuids contains, but it doesn't work because my array of uuids is not live, so my changes won't be triggered by the fact that I add or remove uuids from the uuids array.

Second strategy, is to add a transient property in the model to know where to display which objects. The problem is that if both screen contains object C, then the transient property will be updated on the last screen I visit and the object won't be visible on the previous screen since the transient property is modified.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to explicitly hang onto certain Realm objects in a specific view controller, you can copy those specific objects from the `Results` object to a standard Swift array, which won't be updated if any new items are added.

This solution is pretty transient though. If you want to restore to this view controller from scratch at a later time, then actually persisting this state to Realm (and using a filter like you said) might be the better option.

If that doesn't help, you might need to provide information on what you're actually trying to do here (What do items A, B and C actually represent?) so we can get a better idea of the problem you're trying to solve here. :)

Comment: I did that at a time, but the object kept in a standard Swift array is not a good solution because let's say that I delete an object that is in both screen 1 and screen 2 in screen 2, if I comeback to screen 1, the object will still be in my array and deallocated, so it will crash saying that the object is not valid anymore

Comment: It's possible to check the status of an object by checking its  `object.invalidated` property. When you're returning to this screen, all you need to do is perform a check that that object is still valid, and cancelling that screen completely if it isn't.

Comment: Oh thanks I didn't know ! This is actually awesome. It means that you can eventually filter the array with filter({ !$0.invalidated }) on the viewWillAppear of screen A so it doesn't crash when you get back to that screen !

Comment: Since I wanted to keep the "live" aspect of the objects and arrays (with the cell animation insertion and so), I ended up with this solution :
Added to my object an array "containingClass" where I put self (the view controller name). And my live result goes like this :
`lazy var items: Results<Item> = {
        return Realm().objects(Item.self).filter("ANY containingClass.string == %@", String(self))
    }()`